# How can an arbitrary Num contain any other numeric type?

Tags: haskell

I'm just starting with Haskell, and I thought I'd start by making a random image generator. I looked around a bit and found JuicyPixels, which offers a neat function called `generateImage`. The example that they give doesn't seem to work out of the box.

Their example:

```
imageCreator :: String -> IO ()
imageCreator path = writePng path $ generateImage pixelRenderer 250 300
   where pixelRenderer x y = PixelRGB8 x y 128
```

when I try this, I get that `generateImage` expects an `Int -> Int -> PixelRGB8` whereas `pixelRenderer` is of type `Pixel8 -> Pixel8 -> PixelRGB8`. `PixelRGB8` is of type `Pixel8 -> Pixel8 -> Pixel8 -> PixelRGB8`, so it makes sense that `pixelRenderer` is doing some type inference to determine that `x` and `y` are of type `Pixel8`. If I define a type signature that asserts that they are of type `Int` (so the function gets accepted by `generateImage`, `PixelRGB8` complains that it needs `Pixel8`s, not `Ints`.

`Pixel8` is just a type alias for `Word8`. After some hair pulling, I discovered that the way to convert an `Int` to a `Word8` is by using `fromIntegral`.

The type signature for `fromIntegral` is `(Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`. It seems to me that the function doesn't actually know what you want to convert it to, so it converts to the very generic `Num` class. So theoretically, the output of this is a variable of *any* type that fits the type class `Num` (correct me if I'm mistaken here--as I understand it, classes are kind of like "interfaces" where types are more like classes/primitives in OOP). If I assign a variable

```
let n = fromIntegral 5
:t n -- n :: Num b => b
```

So I'm wondering... what is 'b'? I can use this variable as anything, and it will implicitly cast to any numeric type, as it seems. Not only will it implicitly cast to a `Word8`, it will implicitly cast to a `Pixel8`, meaning `fromPixel` effectively gets turned from (as I understood it) `(Integral a, Num b) => a -> b` to `(Integral a) => a -> Pixel8` depending on context.

Can someone please clarify exactly what's happening here? Why can I use a generic `Num` as any type that fits `Num`, both mechanically and "ethically"? I don't understand how the implicit conversion is implemented (if I were to create my own class, I feel like I would need to add explicit conversion functions). I also don't really know why this works; here I can use a pretty unsafe type and convert it implicitly to anything else. (for example, `fromIntegral 50000` gets translated to `80` if I implicitly convert it to a `Word8`)

Comment: Haskell's numeric classes are pretty shady. They make some rather peculiar assumptions about how numbers work. The first shady assumption in play here is that if something is a numeric type (`Num`) then there must be a way to build values from integers: `fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a` is a method of the `Num` class. The next shady notion is that there's a sensible concept of a numeric type being "integral" (`Integral`), which among other things gives the odd method `toInteger :: Integral a => a -> Integer`. (cont)

Comment: Smashing these strange ideas together gives `fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b; fromIntegral x = fromInteger (toInteger x)`. As you probably can see quite easily, this bizarre hack would lead to horribly inefficient coercions, which is why the standard library is full of compiler rewrite rules to patch them up to sanity.

Comment: Wow, I see. That's pretty bad, and it explains how you can convert 50000 to 80 implicitly by accident, as the `fromInteger` method for `Word8` can basically do whatever it wants even though it's called implicitly.

Comment: The only time it's called implicitly is when reading numeric literals. The rest of the time, you just have to know how it behaves. In some ways, it's nice that it just chops high bits off as needed. Going from a larger type to a smaller one (but not the other way around), `fromIntegral x + fromIntegral y = fromIntegral (x + y)` and `fromIntegral x * fromIntegral y = fromIntegral (x * y)`.

Comment: I don't understand why it calls it when reading numeric literals. In this case, `n` is a `Num b => b` that can be used as a `Word8` without explicit cast. Is `fromIntegral` not called when that happens? If not, what is called implicitly? I imagine it's whatever function that converts `Num b => b` to `Word8` that chops off the bits.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying there. A numeric literal that looks like an integer is interpreted as meaning, say, `fromInteger 5` (where that's a special `Integer`-only `5`) and given type `Num a => a`. A numeric literal that does not look like an integer is interpreted as meaning, say, `fromRational 4.79` and given type `Fractional a => a`. Thus `5` can be used for *any* `Num`, but `4.79` can only be used for `Fractional` things.

Comment: If I have a Num 5 (which for the sake of argument I get from saying `fromIntegral 5`, it calls `fromInteger . toInteger` (which is how `fromIntegral is implemented`, but we lose no data. In other words, if I call `toInteger $ fromIntegral 50000`, I get 50000 back. However, if I call `toInteger (fromIntegral 50000 :: Word8)`, I get 80. If I define a `Word8 -> Int` called `integrateWord x` as `toInteger x`, and then I call it with `integrateWord $ fromIntegral 50000`, it returns 80. Some conversion from Int to Word8 is happening implicitly. Where is that?

Comment: That comment got mangled, unfortunately. I'm not sure how. If I have a `Word8 -> Int` which is implemented as `toInteger x` and I pass it the literal `50000`, I get back 80. Where does the conversion from `50000 :: (Num a) => a` to `80 :: Word8` happen? Some function must be called implicitly.

Comment: The `fromInteger` function is implicitly called for every literal that looks like an integer. When you see `50000` in the source, you need to read it as `fromInteger #50000`, where `#50000` is a made-up name for the version that is always `Integer`. So `toInteger 50000` is read as `toInteger (fromInteger #50000)`.

Comment: I understand, but that returns  a `Num`, not a `Word8`. My question is now how `Num` gets converted to `Word8` (the conversion from literal/`Integer` to `Num` obviously does not chop off all but one byte)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91317/discussion-between-dfeuer-and-river-tam).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common implementation of type classes such as `Num` is dictionary-passing. Roughly, when the compiler sees something like

```
f :: Num a => a -> a
f x = x + 2
```

it transforms it into something like

```
f :: (Integer -> a, a -> a -> a) -> a -> a
  -- ^-- the "dictionary"
f (dictFromInteger, dictPlus) x = dictPlus x (dictFromInteger 2)
```

The latter basically says: "pass me an implementation for these methods of class `Num` for your type `a`, and I will use them to produce a function `a -> a` for you".

Values such as your `n :: Num b => b` are no different. They are compiled into things such as

```
n :: (Integer -> b) -> b
n dictFromInteger = dictFromInteger 5   -- roughly
```

As you can see, this turns innocent-looking integer literals into functions, which can (and does) impact performance. However, in many circumstances the compiler can realize that the full polymorphic version is not actually needed, and remove all the dictionaries.

For instance, if you write `f 3` but `f` expects `Int`, the "polymorphic" `3` can be converted at compile time. So type inference can aid the optimization phase (and user-written type annotation can greatly help here). Further, some other optimizations can be triggered manually, e.g. using the GHC `SPECIALIZE` pragma. Finally, the dreaded monomorphism restriction tries hard to force non-functions to remain non-functions after translation, at the cost of some loss of polymorphism. However, the MR is now being regarded as harmful, since it can cause puzzling type errors in some contexts.

Comment: I think I understand, for the most part. I guess it's fascinating and a bit hard to reason about how in Haskell you can actually have a "generic type" object. I think in the future I'll basically always try to do explicit casts. I'm a bit surprised requiring explicit casts isn't required in the language, as I imply in the question.

Comment: Just to clarify, and please correct me if I'm wrong, but essentially the `dictFromInteger` function is defined somewhere (probably by another name) by the library that defines `Word8`, and this is the function that is free to give up data (e.g. 50000 -> 80)

Comment: @RiverTam Yes, it is indeed defined alongside the definition of `Word8`. Note that in Haskell we do not call `someExpression :: SomeType` a "cast", since this does not always lead to data conversion -- we prefer to call that a "type annotation". E.g. in `[] :: [Char]` the type is used only to instantiate the polymorphic type of the empty list; in `id :: Int -> Int` we similarly instantiate the polymorphic function into a monomoprhic one. No conversion is ever performed here.

Comment: @RiverTam It is also used to pick a specific instance of a type class: if I write `(+) :: Int->Int->Int` I make the compiler search for `instance Num Int` in the imported modules, and find the actual implementation of `(+)`. This also happens, implicitly (!), if I write `(2::Int) + 4` since the compiler can deduce the exact type of `(+)`. Similarly for `f :: Int->Int ; f x = x+1`. Type information is propagated outwards and inwards during type inference.